# Can I connect my python script with Oracle database without downloading its client?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, cx-oracle, oracle19c

I have an old program which uses cx_Oracle with Oracle 11g. This program is not portable as the user need to download Oracle 11g in order to use it. Is it possible to use Oracle database in my script but without downloading it, may be by using any online database?

Comment: If the DB is 'remote' from your users, then simply install the latest Instant Client (currently 19c) on the user machines from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html  It's free, simply unzips, and 19c will let your apps connect to 11g Databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your problem, What I understood is that you need a portable database. Since your scripts are connected to Oracle 11g with cx_Oracle , I guess you used SQL queries everywhere.
I suggest you to use SQLite instead of cx_Oracle if you are in a hurry. Both have kinda similar syntax for executing queries though you may need to modify some keyword.
To start quickly refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle software can be downloaded from the Oracle Technology Network, [here](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/#category-database).

If you want to use an online database, Oracle offers [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/), but I don't think it offers 11g as it is quite old (will be desupported soon). Also, I don't know whether you can (or can not) connect your Python application to it; you'll have to contact Oracle or wait for someone else who knows that info.

Maybe someone hosts 11g, but I doubt that it is for free so - maybe your best option is to download and install free [Oracle 11g Express Edition (XE)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index-100989.html).

Comment: It's not a problem, I can modify my code manually. I just want to keep using SQL queries no matter what database I am using. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Eg I can use sqlite3 easily but I doubt how much data it can hold.

Comment: Then it is 11g XE. Simple to install, in a few NEXT-NEXT clicks.

Comment: Why use XE 11g when XE 18c is available ? ! https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html

Comment: Two reasons I can think of, @Christopher: because the OP says they use(d) 11g with Python, and because it is somewhat simpler than later database versions (PDB? CDB? Huh?).

Comment: @Littlefoot I didn't mean that. The program is still not portable. IF I use sqlite3, I don't need any additional software and it will be local. If I can get a remote database, it will be better.

Comment: That's probably why it is called **lite**. Oracle isn't *lite*, never was (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the reply.